# Python: How can i get text from a tag like this in BeautiflSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get the date and hour of this links : 'https://www.pagina12.com.ar/225378-murio-cacho-castana-simbolo-del-macho-porteno' or any in the site 'https://www.pagina12.com.ar/'.

the structure is this:

```
<div class="article-info"><div class="breadcrumb"><div class="suplement"><a href="https://www.pagina12.com.ar/suplementos/cultura-y-espectaculos/notas">Cultura y Espectáculos</a></div><div class="topic"></div></div><div class="time"><span datetime="2019-10-15" pubdate="pubdate">15 de octubre de 2019</span><span> · </span><span>Actualizado hace <span class="article-time" data-time="1571156914">3 hs</span></span></div></div>
```

and i did this:

```
cosa = requests.get('https://www.pagina12.com.ar/225378-murio-cacho-castana-simbolo-del-macho-porteno').text
parse = BeautifulSoup(cosa, 'html5lib')
info = parse.findAll('div', {'class':'article-info'})
```

then i try to get the text that says '3 Hs' and cant access to it and dont know how to do it. Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you use this: `parser.find('span', {'class': 'article-time'}).get_text()`

Comment: Yes, it give back ' ' as if there's nothing there

Comment: so, you should use this: `parse = BeautifulSoup(cosa, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Can you add the output you are expecting

Comment: Do you want **15 de octubre de 2019** or **2019-10-15** with **1571156914**

Comment: I Want the '3 Hs'  from the

**data-time="1571156914">3 hs</span>**

Comment: The value 3hs that you are looking for is being passed by javascript (I guess), which is done Dynamically, thats why when we try to access article-time nothing is being returned.

Comment: do you mean that I would have to do the scrapping in javascript ? or there is another way. Anyway, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate from the `data-time` attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

r = requests.get('https://www.pagina12.com.ar/225378-murio-cacho-castana-simbolo-del-macho-porteno')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
dt1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(soup.select_one('[data-time]')['data-time']))
dt2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) 
diff = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(dt2, dt1)
print(diff.hours)
```

Comment: I have a question, the number 1571156914 is the hour in seconds and fractions of seconds ? or what does it mean and how did you saw it ?

Comment: it's epoch. See https://www.epochconverter.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Where is this calculation made on the page itself (so that the time differential in hours can be displayed)?

Comment: @JackFleeting I didn't look but it is dynamic. I can have a look now if you want? I suspect you will find it in the source js for the page.

Comment: Yes, please, if you have the time. I'm afraid anything js is (well) above my pay grade...

Comment: @JackFleeting Starts line 108 in https://www.pagina12.com.ar/assets/js/main.min.js?v=1.0.169  That is the call which populates the element content so you track that call back.